# Use Take to including entity

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two tables: categories and articles. One category can have many articles. I want to display overview of new articles separated by categories. But I want to display only first five articles per each category. How should I write query to solve this?

My first idea was something like this:

```
var cat = from c in ctx.categories
          where c.IsPublic == true
          select c;
```

But this contains all articles and I'm not sure how to write something like c.articles.Take(5) to query. Is it possible?

Oh, and it is ASP.NET MVC 2 with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me. Important here is to switch off lazy loading to avoid that all articles are loaded when you iterate through the collection:

```
ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // assuming you are in EF 4.0

var query = ctx.categories
    .Where(c => c.IsPublic)
    .Select(c => new { 
        Category = c, 
        Articles = c.Articles.Take(5)
    }).ToList().Select(x => x.Category);

foreach (var category in query)
{
    foreach (var article in category.Articles)
    {
        // runs only 5 times through this loop
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you don't dispose `ctx` and work with the context more after the code snippet above you probably better reenable lazy loading again ...

```
ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

... before you get into trouble with other queries if your application mostly relies on lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.categories
    .Where(c => c.IsPublic)
    .Select(c => new 
    { 
        Category = c, 
        Articles = c.Articles.OrderBy(a => a.Whatever).Take(5)
    ).Select(c => c.Category);
```

Supposing that your class name is Category with an EntityCollection called Articles, this should work.

Comment: This don't work. Or I not use it properly. I use two nested foreach cycles. First iterate through categories and second through category.Articles. Is it correct approach?

Comment: I believe the last Select will drop eager loading of the Articles. Try to insert a "greedy" operation which executes the query before the last projection, so change the last line to: `...).ToList().Select(c => c.Category);`

Comment: No. It still returns everything and not just five articles.

Comment: Well, I did something like this and it worked for me, but as i said, your class Category must be the exact name of the class and Articles the navigation property. after that you should be able to use category.Articles

Comment: @Ladislav: Do you mean that Category.Articles is null (or empty) in the anonymous type? I tried this model and it seemed to work for me (see my answer). Maybe I misunderstood something or did something wrong?

Comment: @Slauma: You are right. My comment is wrong, I'm going to delete it.

Comment: @Ladislav: Now I believe your comment was actually correct with respect to the query in this answer here. I had inserted a `.ToList()` in my answer. Without ToList `Category.Articles` in the anonymous type is indeed `null`, but with ToList it has the expected 5 elements.